# SMTP alert not working for keepalived

Tags: linux, smtp, load-balancing, keep-alive

I have been working on a project that will establish a set of highly available load balancers.  The load balancing and high availability software seems to work just fine (I am using Crossroads to load balance, and Keepalived to make the load balancing servers highly available, and Conntrackd for health checking of the load balancers) but I am having problems setting the configuration file for Keepalived to send emails when a state transition occurs (master->backup/backup->master).  I have followed the instructions on the man pages (man keepalived.conf) telling me how to set up the emailing notification but I fail to receive emails at expected times.  I am prone to spelling checks and simple error, but after looking over this problem for nearly 10 hours I can't seem to find anything and am running out of things to try.

One of the servers I am using (i'll name it loadbalance1) will sometimes use the smtp_alert to send emails when a change occurs but it will only notify me when it has transitioned from the backup to master (not master to backup).  When it doesn't work, the log files (/var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog) notifies me that an SMTP error status 550 occurs.  I understand these issues to be something relating to an incorrect email address specified in the configuration file, but they are correct as far as I can tell.  The only thing that I have that suggests that keepalived or my configuration file is wrong is that sysadmin emails people with messages about '{' being an improper mail recipient.  I have smtp port open on the computer.  Another odd thing that is happening is sometimes when keepalived tries to contact the mail server, it wants to look at the local machine when it isn't there.  I specify the mail server as being elsewhere but it wants to look locally for some reason.

The other server, loadbalance2 will never send the smtp_alert to send emails regardless of whatever state transition it makes.  I can see in the log files for keepalived (/var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog) that the backup server, loadbalance2, does make the transition to the MASTER state, but it never sends the email.  It gives the same error as loadbalance1, but it just never works here.  It has the same configuration file as loadbalance1.

The following is the configuration file, keepalived.conf

```
    global_defs 
    {
        notification_email 
        {
    fakeemail@example.com
        }
       notification_email_from sysamin@example.com
        ##Mail server below##
       smtp_server www.xxx.yyy.zzz
       smtp_connect_timeout 30
       lvs_id NLB_MASTER
    vrrp_sync_group
    {
        group
        {
            loadbalance1
            loadbalance2
        }
        ##The following scripts don't seem to work properly either##
        ##The scripts are not executed at expected times        ##
        notify_master "/path/to/script.sh master"
        notify_backup "/path/to/script.sh backup"
        notify_fault  "/path/to/script.sh fault"
        notify  "/path/to/script.sh"
        smtp_alert
    }
    vrrp_instance loadbalance1
    {
        state MASTER
        interface eth0
        virtual_router_id 20
        priority 100
        #In some examples online smtp_alert is here
        virtual_ipaddress
        {
            www.xxx.yyy.zzz/24 brd www.xxx.yyy.255 dev eth0
        }
        ##Not entirely sure if this is correct##
        notify_master "/path/to/script.sh master"
        notify_backup "/path/to/script.sh backup"
        notify_fault  "/path/to/script.sh fault"
        notify  "/path/to/script.sh"
        smtp_alert
    }
    vrrp_instance loadbalance2
    {
        state MASTER
        interface eth0
        virtual_router_id 30
        priority 100
        #In some examples online smpt_alert is here
        virtual_ipaddress
        {
            www.xxx.yyy.zzz/24 brd www.xxx.yyy.255 dev eth1
        }
        ##Not entirely sure if this is correct##
        notify_master "/path/to/script.sh master"
        notify_backup "/path/to/script.sh backup"
        notify_fault  "/path/to/script.sh fault"
        notify  "/path/to/script.sh"
        smtp_alert
      }
```

If there are a few inconsistencies in the configuration file I apologize.  Any suggestions, help, or opinions are appreciated.  If you need any more information i'll be happy to oblige.

Comment: any pattern to when the e-mails do go out vs. when they don't?

Answer (score 2):

For those who may be facing the same problem I managed to fix the problem.  I am unsure if it is THE solution, but it may have contributed.

-I had to change the date and time of the machines to the current time (one of them was off by several years due to it being a clone).  Email server may have been blocking the backend server's emails because of the gap in system times?

-Date -s hh:mm:ss

-Date -s year-month-day

-Had to fix a problem with having the same hostname on both machines.  As I said it was a clone of the other and I never changed it on accident.  I may have been getting notices from the backend server all along but never distinguished between the two because I got emails from the same hostname

-Made a minor change to the configuration file that should be negligible

```
    global_defs
    {
          notification_email {
              user@domain.com
          }
    }
```

Not sure if that made the difference but oh well...it works now

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve a simliar issue I was seeing in keepalived.log:

```
SMTP connection ERROR to [0.0.0.0]:25
```

Where my keepalived.conf looked like:

```
global_defs {
  notification_email {
    ....
  }
  notification_email_from somplace@somewhere.com
  smtp_server smtp.somehwere.com
  smtp_connect_timeout 30
  ...
}
```

I updated my smtp configuration to use IP address rather than hostname for my smtp server:

```
smtp_server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Resulting in new output and successful email notifications after restarting keepalived:

```
Remote SMTP server [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:25 connected.
```